# Datetime error, After converting column to datetime unable to perform mathematical operations

Tags: typeerror, datetime-format

I have a dataframe and converted two date columns via to_datetime.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WisdO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJECD.png) Now I am trying to subtract two columns to get difference in months[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHUj0.png). But I believe python is still treating those columns as str.
Kindly help with where have I gone wrong.

I wanted the result in months but the the Type error : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str. Keeps coming. I know i am doing a silly mistake somewhere but unable to figure out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.